# .net custom Identity provider -implement login/logout functionality

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to create a custom identity provider to use in my asp.net core app that uses my legacy code to validate username and password.

This article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1 explains  the architecture and suggests to rewrite only the "store" and "data" layer, moreover, implementing only the interfaces you need.

But these intefaces don't have any of login/logout methods.
Maybe this operation must be performed in the upper layer, the  "IdentityManager" layer? (UserManager)

I need (for now) only the login/logout functionality but i can't understand where to implement this methods.
Any idea or suggestion?

## [EDITED]

as **Fei Han** has suggested me i'm trying to implement a custom `SignInManager`.
I did the following with success:

a custom `SignInManager`:

```
public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<IdentityUser>
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public MySignInManager(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser> claimsFactory,
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
            ILogger<SignInManager<IdentityUser>> logger,
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
            IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider,
            IUserConfirmation<IdentityUser> userConfirmation
            )
            : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemeProvider, userConfirmation)
        {
            _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
            _db = dbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
        }

        public override async Task<SignInResult> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            SignInResult result;
            if (userName == "pippo" && password == "pippo")
            {
                return SignInResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return SignInResult.Failed;
            }
        }
    }
```

then i registered it in the startrup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

        services. ... .AddSignInManager<MySignInManager>();
```

**this mechanism WORKS!**

When i signin, the method `PasswordSignInAsync` on my custom SignInManager is fired!
But, on the subsequentially calls to the api, the `HttpContext.User.Identity` is null.

so the first question is:

**1) should i set the identity in the context on my own(explicitly)? and if yes, where?**

I've explored the source code in the official .net core repository https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Identity  and i've noticed that:

the implementation of the `SignInManager` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/SignInManager.cs behaves more or less like mine (to be more precise, it doesn't set the `HttpContext.User.Identity` inside itself)
So, at firts, i though that `HttpContext.User.Identity` was setted by the caller of `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`  (just after, in case of success login). For the "caller" i mean in the login page.

but i've notice that in the login page of the .net core official repository https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/UI/src/Areas/Identity/Pages/V4/Account/Login.cshtml.cs nothing is setted after the call to the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`.

so the next question is:

**2) what is the relationship between `SignInManager` and `HttpContext.User.Identity`?** probably, i miss a piece.

Comment: It would be good to edit your startup.cs to include that the .AddSignInManager comes after AddIdentity like:
'
 '           services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>()
 '               .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
 '               .AddSignInManager<MySignInManager>();
'

Answer (score 1):

> I need (for now) only the login/logout functionality but i can't understand where to implement this methods. Any idea or suggestion?

[SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-3.1#methods) in ASP.NET Core Identity provides the APIs for user sign in and sign out, you can try to implement a customer SignInManager and override corresponding methods to customize login/logout functionality based on your actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have user information in HttpContext.User.Identity

1. You can update like this, but this will check the user from from the database of applicationDbContex

   ```
      if (userName == "pippo" && password == "pippo")
        {
            //return SignInResult.Success;
         return await base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, rememberMe, 
         shouldLockout);           
        }
   ```
2. Or if you just signInAsync

   ```
      if (userName == "pippo" && password == "pippo")
        {
          var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = userName, Email = userName}; 
            await base.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false); 
            return SignInResult.Success;          
        }
   ```

Hope this helps